# ERROR: Failed building wheel for [Python Package] | Issue with wheels (sometimes)

Tags: python-3.x, windows, bash, pip, scikit-image

Whenever I install a python package that requires wheels, I get this error:

```
$ pip install PyWavelets
Collecting PyWavelets
  Downloading PyWavelets-1.1.1.tar.gz (4.6 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 4.6 MB 344 kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in c:\users\MYUSERNAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from PyWav
elets) (1.19.4)
Building wheels for collected packages: PyWavelets
  Building wheel for PyWavelets (setup.py) ... - ** On entry to DGEBAL parameter number  3 had an illegal value
 ** On entry to DGEHRD  parameter number  2 had an illegal value
 ** On entry to DORGHR DORGQR parameter number  2 had an illegal value
 ** On entry to DHSEQR parameter number  4 had an illegal value
error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\MYUSERNAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0]
 = '"'"'C:\\Users\\MYUSERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8tqnlgrn\\pywavelets\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\MYUSERNAME\\Ap
pData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8tqnlgrn\\pywavelets\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read
().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\Ap
pData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-ns2hq1xm'
       cwd: C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8tqnlgrn\pywavelets\
  Complete output (15 lines):
  C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8tqnlgrn\pywavelets\setup.py:62: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated i
n favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
    import imp
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8tqnlgrn\pywavelets\setup.py", line 477, in <module>
      setup_package()
    File "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8tqnlgrn\pywavelets\setup.py", line 467, in setup_package
      ext_modules = get_ext_modules(USE_CYTHON)
    File "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8tqnlgrn\pywavelets\setup.py", line 182, in get_ext_modules
      from numpy import get_include as get_numpy_include
    File "c:\users\MYUSERNAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 305, in <module>
      _win_os_check()
    File "c:\users\MYUSERNAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 302, in _win_os_check
      raise RuntimeError(msg.format(__file__)) from None
  RuntimeError: The current Numpy installation ('c:\\users\\MYUSERNAME\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\
numpy\\__init__.py') fails to pass a sanity check due to a bug in the windows runtime. See this issue for more information: https:/
/STACKOVERFLOW DOESN'T LIKE TINYURL
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyWavelets
  Running setup.py clean for PyWavelets
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\MYUSERNAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0]
 = '"'"'C:\\Users\\MYUSERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8tqnlgrn\\pywavelets\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\MYUSERNAME\\Ap
pData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8tqnlgrn\\pywavelets\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read
().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' clean --all
       cwd: C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8tqnlgrn\pywavelets
  Complete output (11 lines):
  C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8tqnlgrn\pywavelets\setup.py:62: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated i
n favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
    import imp

  `setup.py clean` is not supported, use one of the following instead:

    - `git clean -xdf` (cleans all files)
    - `git clean -Xdf` (cleans all versioned files, doesn't touch
                        files that aren't checked into the git repo)

  Add `--force` to your command to use it anyway if you must (unsupported).

  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for PyWavelets
Failed to build PyWavelets
Installing collected packages: PyWavelets
    Running setup.py install for PyWavelets ... - ** On entry to DGEBAL parameter number  3 had an illegal value
 ** On entry to DGEHRD  parameter number  2 had an illegal value
 ** On entry to DORGHR DORGQR parameter number  2 had an illegal value
 ** On entry to DHSEQR parameter number  4 had an illegal value
error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\MYUSERNAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[
0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\MYUSERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8tqnlgrn\\pywavelets\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\MYUSERNAME\\
AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8tqnlgrn\\pywavelets\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.re
ad().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\erik
u\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-apt8ex91\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\us
ers\MYUSERNAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\PyWavelets'
         cwd: C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8tqnlgrn\pywavelets\
    Complete output (24 lines):
    C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8tqnlgrn\pywavelets\setup.py:62: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated
 in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
      import imp

    Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
    with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

      - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                               release)
      - `pip install PyWavelets`   (last PyWavelets release on PyPI)


    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8tqnlgrn\pywavelets\setup.py", line 477, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8tqnlgrn\pywavelets\setup.py", line 467, in setup_package
        ext_modules = get_ext_modules(USE_CYTHON)
      File "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8tqnlgrn\pywavelets\setup.py", line 182, in get_ext_modules
        from numpy import get_include as get_numpy_include
      File "c:\users\MYUSERNAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 305, in <module>
        _win_os_check()
      File "c:\users\MYUSERNAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 302, in _win_os_check
        raise RuntimeError(msg.format(__file__)) from None
    RuntimeError: The current Numpy installation ('c:\\users\\MYUSERNAME\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages
\\numpy\\__init__.py') fails to pass a sanity check due to a bug in the windows runtime. See this issue for more information: https
:STACKOVERFLOW DOESN'T LIKE TINYURL
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\MYUSERNAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys
, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\MYUSERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8tqnlgrn\\pywavelets\\setup.py'"'"';
 __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\MYUSERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8tqnlgrn\\pywavelets\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'ope
n'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))
' install --record 'C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-apt8ex91\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed -
-compile --install-headers 'c:\users\MYUSERNAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\PyWavelets' Check the logs for full comma
nd output.
```

I do not know whether this is an issue with wheel or pip!

These are my system specs:

```
Host Name:                 DESKTOP
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
OS Version:                10.0.19041 N/A Build 19041
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Standalone Workstation
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
Registered Owner:          (not leaking my E-Mail here, folks)
Registered Organization:   N/A
Product ID:                (not leaking this either)
Original Install Date:     15/08/2020, 22:55:17
System Boot Time:          07/11/2020, 09:52:30
System Manufacturer:       Micro-Star International Co., Ltd.
System Model:              MS-7B09
System Type:               x64-based PC
Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
                           [01]: AMD64 Family 23 Model 1 Stepping 1 AuthenticAMD ~3500 Mhz
BIOS Version:              American Megatrends Inc. A.70, 14/11/2018
Windows Directory:         C:\WINDOWS
System Directory:          C:\WINDOWS\system32
Boot Device:               \Device\HarddiskVolume6
System Locale:             en-us;English (United States)
Input Locale:              (take a wild guess)
Time Zone:                 (Im always awake)
Total Physical Memory:     65.428 MB
Available Physical Memory: 52.078 MB
Virtual Memory: Max Size:  75.156 MB
Virtual Memory: Available: 52.887 MB
Virtual Memory: In Use:    22.269 MB
Page File Location(s):     C:\pagefile.sys
Domain:                    WORKGROUP
Logon Server:              \\DESKTOP
```

As you see, I'm using BASH for Windows! Anything will help!

(again, PyWavelets is just an example here! This happens with a lot of packages)

I do not know why this occurs, I reinstalled python just today etc. Most things on this machine are fairly fresh and clear. If you can read anything out of these errors, I'd be very thankful if you could post it here.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in windows which is causing this issue as shown in the error message.

The temporary solution is to use numpy 1.19.3. You have 1.19.4.

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip install numpy==1.19.3
```

then run your installation script again.

From [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1207405/fmod-after-an-update-to-windows-2004-is-causing-a.html) Microsoft thread fix will be available around January 2021.

Comment: It did give me another error message, thus did not solve my issue, sadly!

Comment: This is the error message as a .txt file! I hope that helps!

https://1drv.ms/t/s!AmSwzY0NEPj1jcdMQz9erZu3rJv6lw?e=CkaNQC

Comment: I also use python3.9

Answer (score 0):

This occurred because I was using Python3.9 which is fairly new, which is why none of the packages I was using (including wheel) worked. This is a python error.

Installing python 3.8 (and adding it to the PATH) fixed the issue